# function passed as parameter refreshed before callback calls the function

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a complicated web-page that I cannot reproduce here easily with lot iframes. My requirement is to make communication between the two iframes. In one of the scenarios, I refresh the first iframe and the second is left untouched. The two iframes belong to a parent iframe called "portal", I can access that memory space using window.parent in either of my 2 iframes.

I have a function in iframe 2 that registers a callBack on my first iframe on some event(here: obj.onAddition).

```
 addCB = function(callBack) {
        if (callBack != undefined) {
            callBack.token = obj.onAddition(function(a) {                                       
                callBack("ADDED")
            });             
        }
    };
```

During normal operations, I have registered my callback on iframe2. callBack is a function on iframe1.

When I refresh iframe1, the callBack fucntion is ofcourse redefined, and all the references inside it is refreshed.

obj.onAddition event occurs in iframe2, for which the call back function in iframe1 should be called, but since the original function doesn't exist, some cached version? of it is called and it throws an error saying "window" is null(I have a reference to window).

My question is: Is it possible to create a reference of the callBack function such that even after refresh, the new callBack gets called?

I can understand that this explanation only makes sense in my head because I know the underlying code. Please let me know if any other info is needed.

EDIT: I do not have access to modify iframe2's code.

Comment: No, once it is destroyed the reference is gone. Why not use messaging? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I don't have access to modify the iframe2 code. I will look more into this

Comment: Well if you do not have access than you basically are out of luck.